# Is there any operation on two numpy array to discard zero values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have two numpy array x1 and x2 like below:

```
x1 = np.array([[0,2,9,1,0]])
x2 = np.array([[7,3,0,6,8]])
```

Is there any operation like:

```
x2(operation)x1 = array([[ 0,  3,  0,  6, 0]])
```

i.e. if `x1` or `x2` is `0` at any index then make the result array's index value as zero. Otherwise, keep `x2` as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
x3 = np.where(x1 == 0, x1, x2)
print(x3)
```

Output:

```
[[0 3 0 6 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to keep `x2` but make it zero in the case `x1` is zero, just multiply `x2` by the boolean of `x1`.

```
>>> x2 * x1.astype(bool)
array([[0, 3, 0, 6, 0]])
```

Note that if x2 is zero, the result is zero as expected.

Comment: This is elegant.